# Deploy 2 pods gateway api then got token expired error

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster, api-gateway, jhipster-gateway

I deploy my gateway api on k8s, I sync token with **spring session hazelcast**. It's work fine until I scale replica to 2, hazelcast session cluster worked but when I login (with keycloak) and then when call API, some api get 500 internal error and gateway log error **"Expired token"**.
I don't understand why, because it's a new session in session cluster why it expired ?

Comment: Did you try to run the gateway under debugger and inspect variables?

Comment: I don't know deploy 2 api gateway locally, how can do that?

Comment: Nothing specific to JHipster or Kubernetes here, it's pure Spring Boot. You configure a different port for each instance by setting `server.port` property on command line or using another profile, then you start your application by running the main class from IDE. There are alternatives using remote debugging and maven or gradle, but this main class is the simplest. Alternatively, you could to deploy in Kubernetes and do remote debugging.